# Pyodbc with my MSSQL from todays date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I need help. I'm using pyodbc and have gotten contact with server and with my table. but I want to just get new updates from todays date.
I have used `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Disk")`

but with this I get like 6000 rows. and from date 26.February to todays date.
how can i just get from todays date or one week ahead?

example
`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt > todays_date")`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information about the table schema, please?

Comment: done =) i think, im pretty new to this world of programming

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql date and time functions.
For example to see entries from today:
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt > CURRENT_DATE")

More at:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks Gautam840, but unfortunatly it didnt work. i get the error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Programmering\Blattdata\sql.py", line 8, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt > CURRENT_DATE")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.205.14\WHATSUP;DATABASE=Monitor;UID=username;PWD=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

It then returns data from the MSSQL server with in this order

Custid, servername, drive, dt, size_mb, free_mb, last_reboot, last_update, wblastSuccesfull, wblastbackup, TempID

('BIOBE     ', 'SBS       ', 'C:        ', '26.02.2016', '279       ', '151       ', '36        ', '38        ', '25.02.2016', '25.02.2016', 453)

but since there are alot data TempID goes from 456 to 6023 and dates back to february i want to fetch just from todays date and/or 1 week. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have been trying a different thing, cause since I live in Norway, we have a different date format... we have dd.mm.yyy eksample: 24.12.2016

```
import pyodbc
import datetime

format = "%d.%m.%Y"
today = datetime.datetime.today()
s = today.strftime(format)
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
print (d.strftime(format))

c = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.205.14\WHATSUP;DATABASE=Monitor;UID=sa;PWD=WhatsUp_Gold')
cursor = c.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt = '27.04.2016'")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

and with this i get output:

> 27.04.2016 <--this is because of the print (d.strftime(format))"
>
> (' Aconte        ', 'Srv1           ', 'C:        ', '27.04.2016', '466       ', '302       ', '6         ', '6         ', '          ', '          ', 6699)

now how can i change this ["SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt = '27.04.2016'"
to something like this
"SELECT * FROM Disk WHERE dt = 'CURRENT_DATE'"?